# Multiple Filter in the same column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sql table with some values and a lot of filters

```
ID | Name  | Filter1 | Filter2 | Filter3 | Filter4 ... and so on...
```

As now the filters have been set as int and I am running a query as follows to get the data required

```
select Name 
from tblABC 
where Filter1=1 and Filter2 = 7 and Filter3 = 33 ... and so on...'
```

My issue is that I want a filter column to hold multiple numbers. eg:- row no 3 will have numbers 8 and 13 in Filter1 cell, so that when I run a query for 8 or 13 I get the same result. 
ie I want both the below queries to return the same result.

```
select... where  Filter1=8 
select... where  Filter1=13
```

How can this be done? I tried converting the Filter columns to nvarchar and entering data as .8.13. where '.' where was used as separators. After this, running a query 'select... where Filter1 LIKE '%.8.%' is working for me.. But there are like 12 Filter columns and when such a string search is run in large volumes, wouldn't it make the query slow. What would be a more efficient way of doing this?

I am using Microsoft SQL 2014

Comment: can you show some sample data?

Comment: Based on how your data is structured, string comparisons like `'%.8.%'` will lead to table / index scans and cause performance issues specially if you start doing this for 12 columns. can you define large volumes? 10k, / 100k / 10000k?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more efficient way, hmm. Separating *tblABC* from the filters would be my suggested way to go, even if it's not the most efficient way it will make up for it in maintenance (and it sure is more efficient than using like with wildcards for it).

```
tblABC            ID    Name
                  1     Somename
                  2     Othername

tblABCFilter      ID    AbcID     Filter
                  1     1         8
                  2     1         13
                  3     1         33
                  4     2         5
```

How you query this data depends on your required output of course. One way is to just use the following:

```
SELECT tblABC.Name FROM tblABC
INNER JOIN tblABCFilter ON tblABC.ID = tblABCFilter.AbcID
WHERE tblABCFilter.Filter = 33
```

This will return all *Name* with a *Filter* of *33*.

If you want to query for several Filters:

```
SELECT tblABC.Name FROM tblABC
INNER JOIN tblABCFilter ON tblABC.ID = tblABCFilter.AbcID
WHERE tblABCFilter.Filter IN (33,7)
```

This will return all *Name* with *Filter* in either *33* or *7*.

I have created a small [example fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bda05/1)

Comment: lol u never understand the OP requirement ... he has stored 8 and 13 in 1 column 1 record meaning id = 1 and data = 8,13(or something like this) your query will not work

Comment: No, that was his attempt at a solution. I'm suggesting a better one. _What would be a more efficient way of doing this?_

Comment: but man he already told that he has already large volume so you are telling him that just dump that large volume of data and create from the scratch ... is it feasible ... what u think ?

Comment: To fix a bad data storage solution? Of course it is. He is looking for a better way to do it. This is way better, but there are obviously more solutions. Feel free to add your own.

Comment: this looks like a reasonable solution. you could even add a `filterNo` column to the `tblABCFilter` table to enable it to handle all filters. It would however lead to 12 joins with `tblABCFilter`

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to post a solution I use. I use a split function ( there are a lot of SQL Server split functions all over the internet)

You can take as example

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitString]
    (
        @List NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @Delim VARCHAR(255)
    )
    RETURNS TABLE
    AS
        RETURN ( SELECT [Value] FROM 
          ( 
            SELECT 
              [Value] = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@List, [Number],
              CHARINDEX(@Delim, @List + @Delim, [Number]) - [Number])))
            FROM (SELECT Number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name)
              FROM sys.all_objects) AS x
              WHERE Number <= LEN(@List)
              AND SUBSTRING(@Delim + @List, [Number], LEN(@Delim)) = @Delim
          ) AS y
        );
```

and run your query like this

```
select Name 
from tblABC 
where Filter1 IN (
         SELECT * FROM SplitString(@DatatoFilter,',') and 
      Filter2 (IN (
         SELECT * FROM SplitString(@DatatoFilter,',') and 
..so on.
```

If you have hunderds of thousands of records it may not perform very well. But it should work.

My personal aproch would be a stored procedure and temp tables. Create a temp table with all the values you want to use as filter

```
SELECT * 
INTO #Filter1
FROM SplitString(@DatatoFilter,',')

SELECT *
INTO #Filter2
FROM SplitString(@DatatoFilter,',')
```

then the final select

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable 
WHERE Filter1 IN (SELECT DISTINCT Part FROM #Filter1) and 
      Filter2 IN (SELECT DISTINCT Part FROM #Filter2)
```

I don't think it makes any big difference from the first query, but it is easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution which you can try is to convert the columns to `XML`. Its better than converting the columns to `VARCHAR`. You can use `.exist` to get only the records matching your criteria. Something like this.

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE
(
   [ID] int, [Name] varchar(9),Filter1 XML
)

INSERT INTO @table1
    ([ID], [Name],Filter1)
VALUES
    (1, 'Somename','<Filter>8</Filter>'),
    (2, 'Othername','<Filter>8</Filter><Filter>13</Filter>'),
    (3, 'Thirdname','<Filter>25</Filter>')


DECLARE @FilterValue INT = 8
SELECT Filter1.query('/Filter'),* 
FROM @table1
WHERE Filter1.exist('/Filter[. = sql:variable("@FilterValue")]') = 1
```

**EDIT**

You can even use the `XML` column to store all 12 of your filters. So this filter xml column which store all your filters and their multiple values.

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE
(
   [ID] int, [Name] varchar(9),Filter XML
)

INSERT INTO @table1
    ([ID], [Name],Filter)
VALUES
    (1, 'Somename','<Filter ID = "1"><FilterVal>8</FilterVal></Filter><Filter ID = "2"><FilterVal>3</FilterVal><FilterVal>12</FilterVal></Filter>'),
    (2, 'Othername','<Filter ID = "1"><FilterVal>8</FilterVal><FilterVal>13</FilterVal></Filter><Filter ID = "2"><FilterVal>8</FilterVal><FilterVal>13</FilterVal></Filter>'),
    (3, 'Thirdname','<Filter ID = "2"><FilterVal>12</FilterVal><FilterVal>25</FilterVal></Filter><Filter ID = "3"><FilterVal>33</FilterVal></Filter>')

DECLARE @Filter1Value INT = 8
DECLARE @Filter2Value INT = 12

SELECT * 
FROM @table1
WHERE Filter.exist('/Filter[@ID = 1]/FilterVal[. = sql:variable("@Filter1Value")]') = 1
AND   Filter.exist('/Filter[@ID = 2]/FilterVal[. = sql:variable("@Filter2Value")]') = 1
```